# Saving dynamic fields to the database - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to save the text and select inputs I have added with Append to the database. How do I get the value of the dynamically added select and input fields?

http://jsfiddle.net/qBURS/1848/

```
function register() {
    var count = document.getElementById("buildyourform").childElementCount;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {

    }
    alert(count);
}
```

Comment: `$(".fieldtype").each(function(el, i) { ... })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `$( 'form').serializeArray()` you can get array of input and select values

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/qBURS/1849/

```
$('#register').click(function(){
 var x = $("form").serializeArray();
    $.each(x, function(i, field){
        $("#results").append(field.name + ":" + field.value + " ");
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you give an example over the code that I share very shortly?